# Methods for generating regression data whose target follows an arbitrary distribution

Tags: regression, sampling, simulation, rejection-sampling, synthetic-data

I'd like to generate a regression dataset (independent vars that combine *somehow* into a target or dependent variable).  Generating such a dataset is, in general, easy: we can e.g. pick some $x_i$ at random and sum over $i$ with chosen weights to get $y$.

However, I would like to be able to impose the condition that the $y$ values are distributed according to some arbitrary pre-defined distribution, say normal, log normal, uniform, or any more exotic thing that I can define.

My basic research suggests doing something akin to rejection sampling.  In other words: generate the simple linear regression above and accept or reject the $(\vec{x},y)$ pair based on whether $y$ 'fits' with the desired distribution.

Is this a reasonable approach?  Is there anything to watch out for here in a regression setting that might not apply to generating $y$ in isolation?  What other methods are available?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what quantities are to be specified and what are allowed to vary in finding a solution? It seems you wish to stipulate (a) the marginal distribution of the response and (b) the coefficients. Do you also want to specify the marginal distributions of the regressors, or not? I ask because only (a) and (b) are explicit in the question, but that leaves the situation so loosely defined that there are simple almost trivial solutions. E.g., for each draw $y$ of the response and given coefficients $\beta_j,$ simply pick any solution $(x_j)$ of the equation $\sum \beta_jx_j=y.$

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear; I am just not sure what is reasonable to expect from a method. I would like to generate example pairs $(\vec{x}, y)$ such that the distribution of $y$ (given $\vec{x}$) can be specified and at least some of the $x_i$ are informative for predicting $y$.  If possible, I would also like to specify the distribution of the $\vec{x}$, though this is a secondary goal.  The specific nature of the relationship between the $x_i$ and $y$ is not especially important to me, but preferably it would be a little more difficult than linear.